# Hilt injection for FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm implementing my own app using Hilt. However I ran into a problem when trying to inject a `FragmentStateAdapter`. It created a cycle dependency. How can I solve this? Here's my code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val screensViewPagerAdapter = 
      ScreensViewPagerAdapter(this)
... 
}
```

**FragmentStateAdapter class**

```
class ScreensViewPagerAdapter @Inject 
     constructor(@ActivityContext context: Context) : 
      FragmentStateAdapter(context as AppCompatActivity) {
...
}
```

Comment: Found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850811/dagger-with-hilt-inject-activitycontext-in-adapter-from-module#