# Why I am not able to use mobile authentication with firebase in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I am try to learning android jetpack compose, I have simple app, and I want to use mobile authentication with firebase for my project. I am using MVVM in the project, so when I debug the project, it throw an error like

> You must specify an Activity on your PhoneAuthOptions. Please call
> #setActivity()

for the      `.build()` in the view model, how can I arrange my viewmodel, I did not find any solution on internet, any idea?

**Navigation:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun NavScreen(

) {


val modelAuthentication = 
hiltViewModel<AuthenticationViewModel>.()

val navController = rememberNavController()

NotificationMessage(viewModel = viewModel())

 NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = 
"phone") {
composable("phone") {
        PhoneScreen(navController = navController, 
 modelAuthentication = modelAuthentication) { _, _ ->

        }

    }

    composable("phoneVerify") {
        PhoneVerifyScreen(navController = navController, 
  modelAuthentication = modelAuthentication) { _, _ ->

        }

    }
  }}
```

**viewmodel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(


    ) : ViewModel() {

    private val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    var verificationOtp = ""
    var popNotification = mutableStateOf<Event<String>?>(null)

 private lateinit var baseBuilder: PhoneAuthOptions.Builder

fun setActivity(activity: Activity) {
    baseBuilder = 
PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder().setActivity(activity)

}



    fun send(mobileNum: String) {
        val options = baseBuilder
            .setPhoneNumber("+91$mobileNum")
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setCallbacks(object :
                PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Completed")

                }

                override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
                    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Failed")

                }

                override fun onCodeSent(otp: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(otp, p1)
                    verificationOtp = otp
                    handledException(customMessage = "Otp Send Successfully")

                }
            }).build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }

     fun otpVerification(otp: String) {
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationOtp, otp)
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Successful")

                } else {
                    handledException(customMessage =  "Wrong Otp")

                }
            }
    }


    private fun handledException(exception: Exception? = null, customMessage: String = "") {
        exception?.printStackTrace()
        val errorMsg = exception?.message ?: ""
        val message = if (customMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMsg
        } else {
            "$customMessage: $errorMsg"
        }
        popNotification.value = Event(message)
    }


    }
```

**screen1:**

```
@Composable
fun PhoneScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    modelAuthentication: AuthenticationViewModel,
    onClick: (mobileNum: String, otp: String) -> Unit
) {

    val phoneNumber = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

  val context = LocalContext.current

   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

    println("found activity? ${context.findActivity()}")
    val activity = context.findActivity() ?: 
    return@LaunchedEffect
    modelAuthentication.setActivity(activity)

    }


   OutlinedTextField(
            value = phoneNumber.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
            

                ),
            onValueChange = { phoneNumber.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f)

        )

    Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(285.dp)
                    .height(55.dp),
                onClick = {

                    modelAuthentication.send(phoneNumber.value)
                    navController.navigate("phoneVerify")

                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Custom
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(60)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Next",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        color = white,


                        )

                )
            }
}
```

**screen2:**

```
@Composable
fun PhoneVerifyScreen(
navController: NavController,
modelAuthentication: AuthenticationViewModel,
onClick: (mobileNum: String, otp: String) -> Unit
 ) {

 val phoneNumberOtp = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

 val context = LocalContext.current

   LaunchedEffect(Unit) {

    println("found activity? ${context.findActivity()}")

    val activity = context.findActivity() ?: 
    return@LaunchedEffect
    modelAuthentication.setActivity(activity)

    }

   OutlinedTextField(
            value = phoneNumberOtp.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
            

                ),
            onValueChange = { phoneNumberOtp.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "code") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "code") },
            singleLine = true,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f)

        )

    Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(285.dp)
                    .height(55.dp),
                onClick = {

                modelAuthentication.otpVerification(phoneNumberOtp.value)

                navController.navigate("home")

                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Custom
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(60)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Next",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        color = white,


                        )

                )
            }
}
```

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8), will also help.

Comment: @AlexMamo, tnx for ur article, appreciated, I was read it before, my problem is I am still not able to arrange viewmodel for mobile authentication. I am still not do it

Comment: @AlexMamo actually we need activity context here, not app context, so my solution won't work here. Can you guide how can we get it? I've tried injecting it with `@ActivityContext` instead of `@ApplicationContext`, which leads to [this crash](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2381)

Comment: @PylypDukhov Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850811/dagger-with-hilt-inject-activitycontext-in-adapter-from-module) might help.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I am still not understand why I am not able to create suitable viemodel for mobile phone authentication, I did not find example also on internet, I am still not understand how to implement ur answer to my question.

Comment: @AlexMamo the problem is that `ActivityContext` is only available in `ActivityComponent ` to be injected into activity, but here we need to inject it into view model using `ViewModelComponent`. I don't understand why it's a problem for Hilt, as view model scope is less than or equal to activity scope(or not?).

Comment: @PylypDukhov It should be as you said but I'm not sure why it behaves like that.

Comment: @AlexMamo maybe you can try it out in a sample project and share the result here? I don't have much experience with Hilt so may be missing some basic thing. The short explanation of the question: we have to pass activity object into `PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth).setActivity(...)`, and this should be done in a view model. When we have activity context it's easy to get the activity from it.

Comment: @PylypDukhov I'll try to find some time for that. If you also find a workaround in the meanwhile, share it with us.

Comment: Tnx so much for both of you,  I am searched alots   but still didn't find solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it should be possible to inject activity context using Hilt, and hope to see the solution by @Alex Mamo or someone else.

For now here's hacky solution:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var baseBuilder: PhoneAuthOptions.Builder

    fun setActivity(activity: Activity) {
        baseBuilder = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder().setActivity(activity)
    }

    fun send(mobileNum: String) {
        val options = baseBuilder
            //.setPhoneNumber...
    }
}
```

In your view:

```
val viewModel = viewModel<AuthenticationViewModel>()
val context = LocalContext.current
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@LaunchedEffect
    viewModel.setActivity(activity)
}
```

`findActivity`:

```
fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

Comment: Or you can extend AndroidViewModel class. Nice catch Pylyp ;)

Comment: @AlexMamo interesting, but `androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel` requires `application` constructor parameter, how can I do that?

Comment: All apps that use Hilt must contain a class that extends Application. This class should be annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`. That being said, an AppMudule class already contains an instance of Application. So this instance can be directly added inside the ViewModel class constructor like this `class MyViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {...}`. Now since we have such an object, we can simply get the context using `app.applicationContext`.

Comment: @PylypDukhov, tnx for ur answer, I put `@ApplicationContext context: Context` in viewmodel but still not change, and same error

Comment: @DeveloperInSky check out updated answer for a tmp hacky solution

Comment: @PylypDukhov, it says lateinit property baseBuilder has not been initialized for    val options = baseBuilder line of code in viewmodel, why?

Comment: @DeveloperInSky try adding logs like [this](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/7a3463559b542997e08a6a9c2bb120b2) to see what's going on. If it's not called at all, show how you've implemented my code within your view

Comment: @PylypDukhov, I update question, stilll same error, I missed what?

Comment: @DeveloperInSky you need to replace `PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)` with `baseBuilder`

Comment: @PylypDukhov, done, but still same, even clean and build project again

Comment: @DeveloperInSky still "You must specify an Activity on your PhoneAuthOptions. Please call #setActivity()" or "lateinit property baseBuilder has not been initialized"?

Comment: @PylypDukhov, still says  "lateinit property baseBuilder has not been initialized" for  val options = baseBuilder line of code

Comment: @DeveloperInSky so what's result of this log? `println("found activity...`

Comment: @PylypDukhov, it says "Cannot create PhoneAuthCredential without either verificationProof, sessionInfo, temporary proof, or enrollment ID." for         val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationOtp, otp)

Comment: @DeveloperInSky So it seems that you've solved activity problem? have you tried googling for this new error? I see a lot of SO questions and answers by this request

Comment: @PylypDukhov, actually just now it throw this error, I guess it is due to the activity problem , right?

Comment: @DeveloperInSky I dough so, I think that activity check passed now, and you've faced the next problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to [specify Activity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions.Builder#public-phoneauthoptions.builder-setactivity-activity-activity) since
it is a required parameter of the builder.

You will have to move the code of the builder to your Activity 'cause you're not allowed to have a link to Activity in a ViewModel.

Inside the verification result callback you can call ViewModel's methods to pass the result or exception.

Comment: Tnx so much for ur answer,  but I am not sure how to do it,  I have no activity insidi of the screen1,  because I am using navigation to route  screen2,  how I will use activity in screen 1 ?